# libavcodec: How do I use AVOptions to set up encoder parameters?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec

libavcodec seems to have 3 ways to specify parameters for a codec:

- Certain members of the `AVCodecContext` struct
- values in an `AVDictionary` passed to `avcodec_open2`
- `AVOption`s, which seem to cover everything the other two do

Can I use `AVOption`s to setup all of the encoding parameters? In addition, can `AVOption`s provide sensible defaults? Google doesn't yield any results and there's no example provided in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Look at the examples of `av_opt_*` calls in [doc/examples](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/tree/master/doc/examples). For defaults, call
`av_opt_set_defaults`